# Airflow dag not running when scheduled (while others scheduled at same time, do)?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have 2 dags in airflow, both of which are scheduled to run at 22 UTC time (12PM my time (HST)). I find that only one of these dags is running at this time and am not sure why this would be happening. I can manually start the other dag while the one that works is running, but it just does not start on it's own.

Here is the dag configs for the dag that is running on schedule

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 10, 13),
    'email': [
        'me@co.org'
    ],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'max_active_runs': 1,
}

dag = DAG('my_dag_1', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval="0 22 * * *")
```

Here is the dag configs for the dag that is failing to run

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 10, 13),
    'email': [
        'me@co.org',
    ],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('my_dag_2', default_args=default_args,
          max_active_runs=1,
          catchup=False, schedule_interval=f"0 19,22,1 * * *")
            # run setup dag and trigger at 9AM, 12PM,and 3PM (need to convert from UTC time (-2 HST))
```

From the `airflow.cfg` file, some of the settings that I think are relevant are set as...

```
# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
#parallelism = 32
parallelism = 8

# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
#dag_concurrency = 16
dag_concurrency = 3

# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True

# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
#max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
max_active_runs_per_dag = 1
```

Not sure what could be going on here. Is there some setting that I am mistakenly switching on that stops multiple different dags from running at the same time? Any more debugging info to get to add to this question?

Comment: Did you find the issue which caused this problem? I am facing exactly the same situation

Comment: @JuanLuisRuiz-tagle No. I was considering posting to the Airflow Slack channel (https://airflow.apache.org/community/) (you could too if the issue is very crucial for your case), but ultimately I just scheduled the 2 dags to run a slightly different times (not great, but not terrible).